# Strange syntax error when using ruby injection in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, code-injection

The error I am getting is:

SyntaxError in PagesController#main

> C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:49:
>   syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
>   ...=( if event.starts_at.monday? );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... ^
>   C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:52:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ^
>   C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:54:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ^
>   C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:364:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
>   C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:366:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

but the code I'm trying to write is:

```
<% @events.each do |event|%>
        <%= if event.starts_at.monday? %>

            <p><%= event.name %></p>
            <% end %>

        <% end %>
```

Is this really because of my syntax (which I think seems fine) or is it a problem with my code somewhere?
I am writing this code in _show.html.erb (from calendars controller) which is a partial that is being rendered in my main.html.erb (from Pages controller)

this is the code I'm using to render my partial:

```
<%= render partial: '/calendars/show', locals: {} %>
```

and here are my controllers and models:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  #before_action :require_customer, only: [:main]

  def home

  end


  def main
    @events = current_customer.calendar.events
  end

end
```

my calendar controller:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)

  end

  def create
    @calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)
  end

private
  def calendar_params
    params.require(:customer_id)
  end


  def show
    @calendar = current_customer.calendar
    @events = @calendar.events

  end

end
```

my events controller (just for reference)

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :logged_in?


  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @calendar = current_customer.calendar

  end


  def create

    @calendar = current_customer.calendar

    @event = @calendar.events.build(event_params)

    if @event.save
      redirect_to '/main' #'/main/#{@calendar.id}'
    else
      redirect_to '/compose'
      end

  end

private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:calendar_id, :name, :starts_at, :ends_at) 
  end
```

also here are my calendar and events models:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :events
end


class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar

  end
```

I've been stuck on this for days I just can't seem to find an explanation. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a print tag with a conditional statement. This line

```
<%= if event.starts_at.monday? %>
```

should be changed to

```
<% if event.starts_at.monday? %>
```

Also, you should try to care a little bit about properly indenting your code.

```
<% @events.each do |event|%>
  <% if event.starts_at.monday? %>
    <p><%= event.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Same applies to your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

On following [Simone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34370960/3098330) I wanted to add extra bit of info. as Ruby is more expressive language. I would like to refactor the code snipped a little.

```
<% @events.each do |event|%>
    <p><%= event.name if event.starts_at.monday? %></p>
<% end %>
```